# share image with caption in Instagram in android

Tags: android, instagram

I am not able to share any text in Instagram from my android application, Need to share text(promo code) into Instagram application , How it is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code here , what have u tried

Answer (score 0):

As stated in their docs [Android Intents](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/) there is no example of how to send a caption that will be processed by Instagram app. If I recall well, this was supported in the past. They have details [here](http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing)

The thing that comes through my mind is that you could Copy the text to clipboard, inform the user how to Paste the content in the Instagram caption field in a dialog and then maybe the user will actually paste it.

Comment: if possible text to image conversion and then post ?

Comment: You can always use a app that allows you to add text over images and share that image with Instagram app. I know about the caption because I've used it in my app and had to go with the clipboard approach.